# Embeded video into my website

Tags: html, video, embed

Is there any way to embed video from this site? http://azdrama.net/watch-online-divas-in-distress-episode-01-21600.html

I tried to copy the link in view source mode, but the video address will be change after some period of time.

Appreciated if anyone could help.

Comment: Do you have permission to embed someone else's video in your site?

Comment: I'd guess the link changes to prevent people from embedding this video.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="665" height="460" src="http://azdrama.net/getvideo/embed.php?id=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&amp;w=665&amp;h=435"></iframe>​
```

Comment: this is what i did, after around 10 minutes, the path will change